# VNC grey screen after upgrade to ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, gnome-classic, vnc

The grey screen on a remote VNC session had been succesfully fixed for my 12.10 version by editing the .vnc/xstartup file as in the 12.04 related discussion in this forum. After an upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 recommended by the updater, I've got the grey screen back on the VNC clients. Gnome-classic is installed and the xstartup has not changed. What else did Ubuntu 13 upgrader do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since no-one gave me the apparently simple answer, I had to find out myself. 
Gnome support in Ubuntu 13 has changed such that gnome-classic has to be called as gnome-session-fallback. Hurray. Why are they making it so difficult to use the super easy and handy VNC access?

So, in ./vnc/xstartup, 
replace

```
gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
```

by

```
gnome-session-fallback &
```

And that's it to continue using your iPad on Ubuntu.

for the complete xstartup search for vnc grey screen boot 12.04

Answer (score 1):

So well in 13.10 the VNC-gnome haters added another problem and VNC does produce a grey screen with every thinkable configuration of xstartup or gnome installs and the log files show there is a problem with gnome.
As a result I had to install xfce4, and replace the gnome statement in the xstartup file with:

`startxfce4 &`

It does its job so let's forget about gnome then.

Answer (score -1):

So as we now all know the gnome-session in VNC is still broken in Ubuntu 13.10 and actually XFCE on Ubuntu 13.10 was a disaster since I got the XFCE desktop not only in VNC but also on my normal desktop login, which is hopeless because XFCE is only for lightweight in my view. I then tested LinuxMint with Cinnamon which I found a delight compared to the standard Ubuntu Unity desktop, 'way over the top'.
Once a new LinuxMint environment (on vbox, excellent) with vnc4server is built, just ap-get install xfce4 - you will not be hindered with XFCE for your normal login but if you make your xstartup file like this (yes only these lines are necessary!):

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
startxfce4 &
```

!there you have a good xfce destop in vnc. Only thing for me was that the terminal didnt work - it was there but no interaction in the window. I installed terminator and did not further bother.
All is now well - goodbye plain Ubuntu - hello Mint Cinnamon-XFCE.

Answer (score -1):

Old Ubuntu machine offered to upgrade the 12 LTS to 14 LTS .. OK oh here are these gnome VNC grey screens again .. digging through Gnome forums (other vnc servers run happily Linux Mint) then I noted I need to set Vino params over SSH - got "Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY" (I don't have a desktop!), tried the DBUS shell script - that of course doesn't work, then found out (while vnc is already running and I have a 'Display') , I can issue:

```
DISPLAY=:1 gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

yes that executes without an error
(display number is your vnc desktop number)
but still that grey screen in the vnc terminal...

So again, January 2015, the setting of variables through SSH so that a VNC client will efficiently work on GNOME is still a disaster and the advice stands firm to leave GNOME and install XFCE as above. Not as nice, but ... it works. And installs in a minute instead of spending days to find those (no doubt they will exist) few simple commands that will fix the gnome problem.